# Using Extended Euclidean algorithm question

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

Suppose we have $f=x^5-1$ and $g=x^2-1$ and I have found the gcd using the Euclidean algorithm but I’m trying to find a way of expressing this in the way $$af+bg=1$$ where $f, g \in Q[x] $. I know this is actually quite easy and I could do this before, but somehow I can’t seem to find how to do it.

I have the following
$x^5-1=(x^2-1)(x^3*x)+(x-1) $

$x^3+x=(x-1)(x^2+x+2)+2 $

So gcd is 1 but how can I work backwards to find how to do the question.

Comment: $x^3+x=(x-1)(x^2+x+2)+2 $  was the wrong calculation, should have been $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)+(0) $

Answer (score 1):

$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{2}  - 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  - 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  +  x  \right) } +  \left(   x  - 1 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{2}  - 1 \right)  =  \left(   x  - 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  +  x  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{3}  +  x  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) }{ \left(   x  + 1 \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right)  \left( 1  \right)  -  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  \left(   x^{3}  +  x  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
$$  \mbox{to confirm GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }   $$
$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{2}  - 1 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 1 \right)  \left( 1  \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  - 1 \right)  \left(   x^{3}  +  x  \right)  = \color{blue}{ \left(   x  - 1 \right)  }$$
$$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }   $$